# How to loop through xml values in a batch cmd

Tags: xml, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

if i have the following xml:

```
<a> 
    <b>valA</b>
    <b>valB</b>
</a> 

<c> 
    <b>valA</b>
    <b>valB</b>
</c>
```

and the following cmd:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s server.xml') do (
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=>" %%i in ('findstr "<a>" %%f') do @echo %%i > temp1.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=<" %%i in (temp1.txt) do @echo %%i
```

)

i need to access the values of node b but the above code only will work if i have values like this

```
<a>asdf</a>
```

I only want to iterate through parent element a

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Excuse me. I think I really don't understand what you need, but the Batch file below show the values of node b in server.xml file:

```
for /F "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%i in ('findstr "<b>" server.xml') do echo %%i
```

Result:

```
valA
valB
```

Is this what you want?

**EDIT:** *New version added in accordance with the additional comment*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set fileName=server.xml
findstr /N "<b>" %fileName% > nodesB.tmp
call :seekNodesA < nodesB.tmp
del nodesB.tmp
goto :EOF

:seekNodesA
set lineB=0
set startLine=
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "a>" %fileName%') do (
   if not defined startLine (
      set startLine=%%a
   ) else (
      call :checkNodeB !startLine! %%a
      set startLine=
   )
)
exit /B

:checkNodeB startNodeA endNodeA
if %lineB% gtr %1 goto showNodeB
   set nodeB=99999999:
   set /P nodeB=
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%b in ("%nodeB%") do (
      set lineB=%%b
      set "nodeB=%%c"
   )
goto checkNodeB
:showNodeB
if %lineB% gtr %2 exit /B
   for /F "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%i in ("%nodeB%") do echo %%i
   set nodeB=99999999:
   set /P nodeB=
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%b in ("%nodeB%") do (
      set lineB=%%b
      set nodeB=%%c
   )
goto showNodeB
```

Given this data file:

```
<a>
     <b>valB1-A</b>
     <b>valB2-A</b>
</a>

<c>
     <b>valB1-C</b>
     <b>valB2-C</b>
</c>

<a>
     <b>valB3-A</b>
     <b>valB4-A</b>
</a>
```

Previous Batch file get this result:

```
valB1-A
valB2-A
valB3-A
valB4-A
```

I assumed several details.

Comment: you are excused. and i marked as answer and upvoted, i gess what i needed was to know how to only iterate through the child nodes of a, incase node b was also contained within another parent element. danke

Comment: Is there just one parent node a in the file? Or may be several of them? Each contents of parent node a is in several separate lines?

Comment: Wow, thanks for following up! Never had anyone do that before.  Wish i could upvote that answer again, that worked just as I expected it to.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Though you'll need to add a root element to make the xml valid you can check the [xpath.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat):

```
call xpath.bat "server.xml" "//b"
```